# Correct workflow when using parent NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data

I'm using a chain of `NSManagedObjectContext` to represent a hierarchy of views and actions that can be rolled back/cancelled.
This is one example:
Let's say I have the following structure:

- Client list (Main NSManagedObjectContext)
- Client details (DetailContext - Parent = MainContext)
- Client Groceries (GroceryContext - Parent = DetailContext)
- Grocery Payment (PaymentContext - Parent = GroceryContext)

This way, I can navigate to the Grocery payment, do changes, and cancel if necessary, same thing for all other levels. Since performing a save will move the changes on level up. So far, this is working as expected.

What I want to understand is a good way to do the following:

- Open the client on the list;
- Open the groceries;
- Open the grocery payment record
- Add a transaction

The thing is, that this transaction needs to be saved on the backend as well, and saved on the local main context, because no matter what I do on the rest of the workflow, that transaction was made.

What I've been doing is that in case of a transaction is made, a series of delegates will be called until the root level which is the parent context of all, and save the transaction. But I'm wondering if there is a better way to do it. Because even though a transaction is done, I might want to cancel some other changes that were made during the way. But all those contexts need to have an updated object of that saved context for the transaction since that is final.

Please don't get attached to the actual use case of clients-groceries, this was just to explain the hierarchy level of contexts.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using all these nested child contexts is almost certainly the wrong approach. For the most part you only want the one main context while on the main thread, however if you have a whole bunch of changes that only make sense when done and saved together then you can use a temporary child context for that. When you save the child context then immediately save the main context too to get it onto disk. Think of it like a database transaction.

If you have changes coming in from a background process you can either create a private child context, or a completely seperate private context straight off the persistent store coordinator - you will have to manually merge changes into the main context in the second case though. Use `managedObjectContextDidSaveNotification:` for that.

Comment: I understand your suggestion, but why do you think it's a wrong approach?
If I have a nested chain of screens that can be cancelled on the first one, for example: I have 4 "layers" of context, then I do one change on the 4th context, and save it, then a change on the 3rd and save it, but on the 2nd context the user decides to cancel the entire transaction. I see parent context chained as a good solution for an UX like this, don't you? This way things are only going to be persisted if every step is confirmed (And this is what the UX requires).

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext
 the parent context instead of a coordinator. This pattern has a number of usage scenarios, including:

Performing background operations on a second thread or queue.
Managing discardable edits, such as in an inspector window or view.

Comment: I just think it sounds like an unnecessarily complex approach to have multiple nested contexts like that. In any case use the `managedObjectContextDidSaveNotification:` notification to merge the changes from your transaction into all your other contexts. Each child needs to watch for its parent saving and pull the changes in then.

Comment: Think of it from a user perspective also. Would the user expect to lose all their data if they exited the app after saving at context level 4 and 3 but not right back up to the top. To me 'save' means it's saved and I won't lose it.